# self hosted wcf with ssl with webHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, ssl

I'm have created a  self hosted WCF service that act as REST API service with webHttpBinding and support of CORS. I consume this service from the browser.

When I tried to add https, it didn't work.

I created the CERTS, and combine them according to this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugpPSNxtAmY

my config is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyService.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior">
      <identity>
        <dns value="MyMachine" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior" type="Company.Common.EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior, Company.Common" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
      <webHttp />
      <crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
    transferMode="Buffered">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<standardEndpoints>
  <webScriptEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webScriptEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

When I try to consume I got an error.
How can I do it.
The client of this service is a browser

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial is awesome:

http://www.allenconway.net/2012/05/creating-wcf-restful-service-and-secure.html

it explains exactly what shall be done